# Login to GAE Facebook app

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-login

What is the preferred way to login to a Facebook app powered by Google App Engine?  Should I use the [Javascript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) or is there some way to do it with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to use the Facebook API.  There is a [way to do it with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190346/facebook-api-and-python), but do you really want to manage that code?